# Value behind a pointer changes by printing it

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree

I want to build up a simple binary-tree in C++ using pointers for each node pointing to the left child and to the right child. I set the root of the tree manually, then I add one number to the tree, but by printing its value in the main() the value of the variable behind the pointer changes its value.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int data = 0;
    Node *leftNode = NULL;
    Node *rightNode = NULL;
};

void insertNode(Node *node, int newData)
{
    cout << "Testing Node: " << node -> data << " | " << &(node -> data) << endl;
    //smaller (or equal) or bigger
    if (newData > node -> data)
    {
        if (node -> rightNode == NULL)
        {
            Node newNode;
            newNode.data = newData;
            node -> rightNode = &newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            insertNode(node->rightNode, newData);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (node -> leftNode == NULL)
        {
            Node newNode;
            newNode.data = newData;
            node -> leftNode = &newNode;
            cout << "Added Node: " << (node -> leftNode) -> data << " AT " << &(node -> leftNode -> data) << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            insertNode(node -> leftNode, newData);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    Node firstnode;
    firstnode.data = 42;
    Node *pointer = &firstnode;
    //insert nodes
    /*for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << "Inserting new Element: " << (10 + i) << endl;
        int newI = 10 + i;
        insertNode(&firstnode, newI);
    }*/
    cout << "Inserting new Element: " << (10) << endl;
    int newI = 10;
    insertNode(&firstnode, newI);
    cout << "in main " << firstnode.leftNode -> data << " | " << &(firstnode.leftNode -> data) << endl;
    cout << "in main2 " << firstnode.leftNode -> data << " | " << &(firstnode.leftNode -> data) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Inserting new Element: 10
Testing Node: 42 | 0x61feec
Added Node: 10 AT 0x61fea8
in main 10 | 0x61fea8
in main2 6422216 | 0x61fea8
```

Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Don't use `NULL` in modern C++. Use `nullptr`.

Comment: When you create `newNode`s in `insertNode`, you create them on the stack instead of the heap.  Then they immediately go out of scope, and the pointers you just set up are now dangling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning pointers to non-static local variables.
Non-static local variables will be invalid on returning from the function.
You should dinamically allocate the nodes instead.

In the other words, you should use

```
Node* newNode = new Node;
newNode -> data = newData;
node -> rightNode = newNode;
```

instead of

```
Node newNode;
newNode.data = newData;
node -> rightNode = &newNode;
```

and also do like this for `node -> leftNode`.

Comment: Why does the value change tho? No function is being called. And as far as I understand, nothing have been put on the stack after the first time the value is printed. Why the first printed value is different from the second printed one?

Comment: @StackExchange123 The `<<` operator used for `cout` may be implemented as a function. Function calls use the stack. Some local variables, which also use the stack, may be used in the implementation.